# performing set operations on custom classes in python

Tags: python, set

I'd like to use Python's built-in set class with a custom class that I've created.  If I want
to create sets containing instances of my custom class, what functions do I need to implement so that I can perform tests, like set_a - set_b?

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493307/creating-set-of-objects-of-user-defined-class-in-python

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It will work out of the box, however, there might be cases, when it makes sense to overload [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) and [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). By default, `__eq__` will compare for object identity. This might not be what you want. In that case, you have to take care that equal object have equal hashes, and, ideally, not equal object have different hashes (although this is not required, it merely reduces collisions). You should always implement `__ne__` using `__eq__`, unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise (this is done to ensure logical consistency).

Also, when overloading `__hash__`, you have to take care that the hash does not change while the object is stored in a `set`.

Comment: Thanks, @Space_C0wb0y.  The bit about __eq__ and __hash__ is what I need to know.

Comment: @Danny: Glad to help. If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it using the tick on the left.

Comment: You didn't say how to implement __hash__ which is the critical part here. how to exactly implement it? Second, when you create classes you rarely (I never did till now!) create __eq__ or __ne__ functions. Not needed! so why write otherwise?