# Creating Set of objects of user defined class in python

Tags: python

```
table = set([])

class GlobeLearningTable(object):
    def __init__(self,mac,port,dpid):

        self.mac = mac
        self.port = port
        self.dpid = dpid

    def add(self):

        global table
        if self not in table:
            table.add(self)

class LearningSwitch(object):
    def __init__ (self, connection, transparent):
       self.connection = connection
       self.transparent = transparent
       self.macToPort = {}
       connection.addListeners(self)
       self.hold_down_expired = _flood_delay == 0

    def _handle_PacketIn (self, event):
       packet = event.parsed
       self.macToPort[packet.src] = event.port # 1
       packet_src = str(packet.src)
       packet_mac = packet_src.upper()
       entry = GlobeLearningTable(packet_mac, event.port, dpid_to_str(self.connection.dpid))
       entry.add()
```

Problem : `entry.add()` method adds new object every time it is called and increments the items in the table.

This should not happen because

1. In the add method I am checking that is that object in the table or not , then I am adding that particular object.
2. Table is a set which is unordered list, which should not have duplicate objects.

Help: is there any way in this set up I can add the object only when it's not in the table.

Comment: You probably meant `table = set()` instead of `set([])`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to implement [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) and [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) methods to teach Python about how to recognise unique `GlobeLearningTable` instances.

```
class GlobeLearningTable(object):
    def __init__(self,mac,port,dpid):
        self.mac = mac
        self.port = port
        self.dpid = dpid

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.mac, self.port, self.dpid))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        return self.mac == other.mac and self.port == other.port and self.dpid == other.dpid
```

Now your object is comparable, and equal objects will also return equal values for `__hash__`. This lets `set` and `dict` objects store your objects efficiently and detect if it is already present:

```
>>> demo = set([GlobeLearningTable('a', 10, 'b')])
>>> GlobeLearningTable('a', 10, 'b') in demo
True
```

Comment: @MartijnPeters Isn't the `__eq__` incomplete? Two instances with `None` values can result in being "equal", even though such a behavior is not desired. Such instances can have same hash but may not be equal.

Comment: @JohnStrood: why would they not be equal? If the same attributes on both objects are set to `None`, then they are equal and their hash would be the same. If you are thinking about different attributes (`mac` on one, `port` on the other), they are not equal, and their hash would not be the same either. Position in the tuple *matters* when calculating the hash.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess it's a matter of design. Let's say two objects have the same `mac`, and `port` and `dpid` set to `None`. I would never want those two objects to be equal, as I don't have any information on either `port` or `dpid`. All the three non-null keys in the tuple should determine equality.

Comment: @JohnStrood: then you'll have to deal with that usecase *differently*, but that's not a standard way of handling equality. Note that it's fine for two unequal objects to have the same hash, it's only a problem if two objects that are equal to have different hashes. So just return `False` if there are any `None` attributes if you want those to be un-equal, and leave the hash implementation as it is.