# Check if an object is in a set (Python)

Tags: python, set

Let say I have the following Point Class.

```
class POINT:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x 
    self.y = y 

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

Main function:

```
def main():
  mySet = set()
  a = POINT(1,2)
  mySet.add(a)
  b = POINT(1,2)

  print("B is in mySet= {}".format(b in mySet))
```

I would like to know an efficient way to check if an object(a point) is in a set.

I know two ways to accomplish it, but they are either not efficient or don't use a custom object:

> 1. Traverse through all the point objects in the set --> O(n)
> 2. Use set to represent points. i.e (1,2) in mySet --> not using a custom object

I believe when using the key term `in`, it will check the id or hash values of objects. I wonder what key term allows me to check the values of objects in a set.

Comment: You forgot to implement `__hash__`.

Comment: Add a `__hash__` method to your `POINT` class that will return the same hash for points with the same values

Comment: Also, if Python actually *let* you do `mySet.add(a)` with that `POINT` implementation, you must still be on Python 2. Get Python 3.

Comment: Yeah. When I ran the code, it told me to implement __hash__. How should I implement the hash function? I looked into the documentation. __hash__ supposes to return an integer. Therefore, two different points could have the same hash.

Comment: Yes, two different points can have the same hash. That's completely normal and expected. As long as such collisions are rare, it won't be a problem. (If they're common, you'll see a severe performance penalty.)

Comment: One of the usual ways to implement `__hash__` is to build a tuple of your object's data and take the tuple's hash.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Smart. Would it affect the performance?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I believe performance base on how Python implements tuple's hash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Set of objects of user defined class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493307/creating-set-of-objects-of-user-defined-class-in-python)

Comment: @dspencer Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could rephrase this question to "how to use `in` key term with a custom object?"

We need to define hash in the custom class. How do we do it?

We need to consider two main cases:

1. Avoid collision
2. Efficient

We could get collision if we define `hash = self.x + self.y` because Point(x,y) and Point(y,x) would give the same hash values and it shouldn't be since their x's and y's are not the same.

One way to avoid it is by using a built-in hash function that takes objects. We could convert our `self.x` and `self.y` to a tuple object so that it can be used with the hash function. The efficient of this would be depend on how Python implements the hash().

```
class POINT: 

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.x, self.y))
```