# How to make the "in" and "subset" method of python works?

Tags: python, class, set

I am relatively new to python. I have a class Time, and I want to check if a set of Time objects contains another set of Time objects.

```
a = {Time(10,10)} 
print {Time(10,10)}.issubset(a) >> "result is False"
for i in a:
    print i in a >> "result is True"
```

And in the class, I have implemented these methods

```
def to_min(self):
    return self.h * 60 + self.m
def __cmp__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Time):
        if self.to_min() > other.to_min():
            return 1
        else:
            if self.to_min() == other.to_min():
                return 0
            else:
                return -1
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Time):
        if self.to_min() == other.to_min():
            return True
        else:
            return False
def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() > other.to_min()
def __ge__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() >= other.to_min()
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() < other.to_min()
def __le__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() <= other.to_min()
def __str__ (self):
    return str(self.h) + ":" + str(self.m)
def __hash__(self):
    return self.to_min()
```

I wonder what else should I implement or change to make the following lines of code to print to true. I have read the=at there is a **contains** method. But I am not going check if one Time object contains other components.

```
a = {Time(10,10)} 
print {Time(10,10)}.issubset(a) >>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [performing set operations on custom classes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754440/performing-set-operations-on-custom-classes-in-python)

Comment: Can you `print Time(10, 10).to_min()` and show us the result?

Comment: I think the issue was with my __eq__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this

```
 self.to_min() == other.to_min()
```

with this

```
 self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()
```

And also edited the **eq** to return boollean, rather than integer
Now it works, I still wonders.
Anyway, this is full code if anyone is interested:

```
class Time(object):
'''
classdocs
'''


def __init__(self, h, m):
    if isinstance(h, int) and isinstance(h, int):
        self.m = m
        self.h = h
        if(self.m >= 60):
            self.h += self.m // 60
            self.m %= 60
def __add__(self, m):

    return Time(self.h, self.m + m)
def to_min(self):
    return self.h * 60 + self.m
def __cmp__(self, other):
    print "__cmp__"
    if isinstance(other, Time):
        if self.to_min() > other.to_min():
            return 1
        else:
            if self.__hash__() == other.__hash__():
                return 0
            else:
                return -1
def __eq__(self, other):
    print "__eq__"
    if isinstance(other, Time):
        if self.to_min() == other.to_min():
            return True
        else:
            return False
def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() > other.to_min()
def __ge__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() >= other.to_min()
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() < other.to_min()
def __le__(self, other):
    return self.to_min() <= other.to_min()
def __str__ (self):
    return str(self.h) + ":" + str(self.m)
def __hash__(self):
    print "__hash__"
    return self.to_min()
    # return 1
def __ne__(self, other):
    print "__ne__"
    return not self == other



# a = set([Time(10,10), Time(10,20)])
# b = set([Time(10,10)])
# print a in set([b])
a = {Time(10,10)} 
print {Time(10,10)}.issubset(a) 
# print b.issubset( a)
# for i in a:
#     print i in a
```