# Python: Updating an object within a set

Tags: python

I created this class:

```
class Device(object):
    """Holds searched SSID, searched BSSID and 
       own MAC-Addr information about a device"""

    def __init__(self, mac):
        self.mac = mac
        self.bssid_set = set()
        self.ssid_set = set()

    def add_bssid(self, bssid):
        self.bssid_set.add(bssid)

    def add_ssid(self, ssid):
        self.ssid_set.add(ssid)

    def __str__(self):
        ssid_str = ', '.join(self.ssid_set)
        bssid_str = ', '.join(self.bssid_set)
        return "{mac} has searched for {ssid_str} and {bssid_str}".format(
                mac = self.mac,
                ssid_str = ssid_str,
                bssid_str = bssid_str)
```

and I want to create multiple objects of this class, put them in a set (no duplicates) and update the objects whenever I find a new probe request having another ssid or bssid, so the identifier for the set should be the mac.

Either I'm too blind to see how to use a set properly or I'm trying the wrong stuff here because updating a set just adds a new object but I don't need this.

Would it be wiser to just use a dict like this:

```
mac = 'abcd'
ssid = set(['ssid1', 'ssid2'])
bssid = set(['bssid1', 'bssid2'])
dict[mac] = [ssid.update('newssid'), bssid.update('newbssid')]
```

or what would be the pythonic way to go here?

Edit: accidentally put '' around mac in the dict

Comment: Set identifies the uniques of object based on the value return by `__hash__` function. You may override this function with logic you need to identify the uniqueness of object. Also check: [performing set operations on custom classes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754440/performing-set-operations-on-custom-classes-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with "you're trying the wrong stuff here".

Objects in a set are not supposed to change. If you do something that unexpectedly changes the object hash (or the comparison outcome), bad things will happen and you may get duplicates, or missing objects. Sets also don't allow you to retrieve things by index, so if you need to modify anything, you should look through the whole set and create a new one with the modification you want. (yes, you can implement it in a way that hash and comparison ignore the internal collections, but... why?)

It's probably easier if you just keep a `mac -> Device` mapping in a standard dictionary, since you always have the mac as a natural lookup key.

Comment: OK, I just wasn't sure if I was on the wrong way but it looks like I am. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Defaultdict can do what your class is doing

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
d['mac1']['bssid']=set()
d['mac1']['ssid']=set()
d
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(dict, {'mac1': {'bssid': set(), 'ssid': set()}})
```